# How to output custom field of Content type in page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I want to display a custom field which I created in my custom Drupal theme.

The field I created called "Startnummer" so the machine name of the field (I didn't change it) was created as "field_startnummer".

Furthermore, I found an article of that topic an the answer is to put the following line into my page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print render($content['field_startnummer']); ?>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work!

The next problem is, I do not know how other people would call that problem, so I can't find any solutions.

Any help?

Comment: Controlling the display for a custom field can be done via the core node view modes interface. Do you have a specific reason not to use that? [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752) Other than that the code should work.

Comment: The problem seems to be that in page.tpl.php you shouldn't have content type templating. It is supposed to be done in node--contenttype.tpl.php and required variables are avaliable there, not in page template. If you have any specific reason to break this separation, tell us. It seems it might be XY problem - you have problem X, you think it should be solved doing Y, so you ask us how to do Y, risking you will miss more direct solutions to X.

Comment: If you want to print that field on a specific page, use "node--nodeid.tpl.php" or "node--contenttype.tpl.php" as Mołot mentioned.

Comment: Here is the Theme Hook suggestion documentation https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 0):

To output content types fields within a template you'll need to create a specific node.tpl.php for that content type for example node--article.tpl.php and then using the code you already have above should work.

Answer (score 0):

To print your field in **page.tpl.php** do this:

Add this to your **template.php** file

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    $node = node_load($node->nid);
    node_build_content($node);
    $vars['field_YOURFIELD'] = render($node->content['field_YOURFIELD']);
  }
}
```

Then add this to your **page.tpl.php** file (or page--customname.tpl.php whatever file you are using to render page). We are using if statement here to avoid errors when/if field is empty.

```
<?php
if (isset($field_YOURFIELD)){
   print $field_YOURFIELD;
} 
?>
```

After this you might notice that you are getting field output as double. That is because you have field active in Manage display of your content type (admin/structure/types/manage/YOURCONTENTTYPE/display).

So you need to add one more function to **template.php**.

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_node( &$variables, $hook )
{
    if( $variables['page'] )
    {
      hide($variables['content']['field_YOURFIELD']);
    }
}
```

This one hides field from node content array. So your field is only printed when you are calling it on **page.tpl.php** file.